# Print Firestore array to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FirestoreApp in Google Script to access my Firestore database.
In the database I have a document with an array which I'd like to print out as a table.

Here's my code:

```
var allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("finished/AUG1/2021-3").map(function(doc) {
    return doc.fields;
  });
  const first = allDocuments[0];
  const colum = Object.keys(first);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(colum);
  allDocuments.forEach(function(doc) {
    const row = colum.map(function(clm) {
      //return doc[clm].toString(); //if documents has array use toString();
      return JSON.stringify(doc[clm], null, 4);
    })
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  })
}
```

I get the following in return:

```
"{
    ""arrayValue"": {
        ""values"": [
            {
                ""stringValue"": ""64MR6""
            },
            {
                ""stringValue"": ""64MR6""
            },
            {
                ""stringValue"": ""64MR6""
            }
        ]
    }
}"
```

I'd like to print out all the "64MR6" below or next to each other, but somehow whatever I try I can't seem to get it right.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Puh, here we go:

Easy to amend the logic in case you need to loop through a json object of an object of an object.....

```
var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);

  var allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("finished/AUG1/2021-3").map(function(doc) {
    return doc.fields;
  });
  const first = allDocuments[0];
  const colum = Object.keys(first);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(colum);
  allDocuments.forEach(function(doc) {
    const row = colum.map(function(clm) {
      //return doc[clm].toString(); //if documents has array use toString();
      //return JSON.stringify(doc[clm], null, 4);

      //console.log(console.log(doc[clm]["arrayValue"]["values"][1]).toString());
      for (i=0;i<doc[clm]["arrayValue"]["values"].length;i++)
      {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(doc[clm]["arrayValue"]["values"][i])) {
        //console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        console.log(`${value}`);
      }
      }
      
    })
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  })
}
```